# How to fix error: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async (member) => {
 const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(
  (channel) => channel.name === 'general'
 );

 if (!channel) return;

 const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);

 const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./wallpaper.jpg');
 ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

 ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
 ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

 // Select the font size and type from one of the natively available fonts
 ctx.font = '60px ArialCE.ttf';
 // Select the style that will be used to fill the text in
 ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
 // Actually fill the text with a solid color
 ctx.fillText(member.displayName, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 1.8);

 ctx.beginPath();
 // Start the arc to form a circle
 ctx.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
 // Put the pen down
 ctx.closePath();
 // Clip off the region you drew on
 ctx.clip();

 const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(
  member.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg' })
 );
 // Move the image downwards vertically and constrain its height to 200, so it's a square
 ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

 const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(
  canvas.toBuffer(),
  'welcome-image.png'
 );

 channel.send(`Welcome ${member.toString()} to the server!`, attachment);
});
```

I have been making a discord bot using discord.js. I wanted to make a canvas welcome message then when made it, it was working and all, except the words on the canvas. It was all like this:

[image: screenshot]

and I searched a lot on google but couldn't find any solution.
The error I get is (Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file).
I know it means that there are no fonts in my system but how to add them. I'm using repl.it.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet so i can tell you what's wrong in it..? i think the issue with fontPath './restPath'

Comment: Ok @LakshmanKambam

Comment: @LakshmanKambam DID!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should work in node-canvas 2.0+. checkout new `Canvas.registerFont` method:
https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/#registerfont

To use a font file that is not installed as a system font, use `registerFont()` to register the font with Canvas. This must be done before the Canvas is created.

```
const { registerFont, createCanvas } = require('canvas')
registerFont('./fontFolder/comicsans.ttf', { family: 'Comic Sans' })

const canvas = createCanvas(500, 500)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

ctx.font = '12px "Comic Sans"'
ctx.fillText('Everyone hates this font :(', 250, 10)
```

Example:

TTF file will have a different font name. so only `'Roboto'` here. otherwise it doesn't work.

```
registerFont('./fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf', {family: 'Roboto'})
```

Don't define fontName as `'Medium 28px Roboto'`. it won't work.

```
ctx.font = '12px Roboto Medium';
```

Comment: You ROCK! You fixed the problem don't know how to thank u man!

Comment: good to know that it helped. don't forget to upvote.

Comment: I can't yet cause I don't have 15  reputation.("

Comment: oh i didn't notice. nvm! don't worry... you will get there soon. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the error in a CentOS instance, installing this worked for me.

```
yum install fontconfig
```