# Canvas and discord.js text is all "▯"

Tags: node.js, canvas, text, unicode, discord.js

my code runs first perfectly but now not anymore.

its a welcome card for a discord server.

**here's how it should have looked:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVUwI.png

**and here's how it looks now:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/flUZE.jpg

**here is the code:**

````
client.on("guildMemberAdd",async member => {
        
        var name = member.displayName
        var id = member.id
        var membercount = member.guild.memberCount
        var displayAvatarURL = member.user.displayAvatarURL({format:"jpg"})
    
        var joinimage = Canvas.createCanvas(2000,1000)
        var ctx = joinimage.getContext("2d")
    
        var background = await Canvas.loadImage("./background.png")
    
        ctx.drawImage(background,0,0,2000,1000)
    
        ctx.textAlign = "center"
        ctx.font = '120px Arial';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        ctx.fillText("welkom",1400,400)
        ctx.fillText(name,1400,550)
        ctx.font = '60px Arial';
        ctx.fillText(("Maak veel plezier in PixelKingdoms!"),1400,750)
    
        const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(displayAvatarURL)
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(500, 500, 300, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.clip();
    
        ctx.drawImage(avatar, 200, 200, 600, 600);
        ctx.lineWidth = 20;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath()
    
        
    
        const attachment = new discord.MessageAttachment(joinimage.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');
        member.guild.channels.cache.get("873169519881900033").send("Hey <@"+id+">Welkom in **"+member.guild.name+"**!",attachment)
        var fanrole = member.guild.roles.cache.get("873163741276033084")
        member.roles.add(fanrole)
        
        
    })```
(sorry for bad english)
````

Comment: sorry but it is fixed, read the article here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67135741/how-to-fix-error-fontconfig-error-cannot-load-default-config-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67135741/how-to-fix-error-fontconfig-error-cannot-load-default-config-file)